# Last element in list

Tags: logic, recurrence-relations, computational-mathematics

We have to find the last element not marked in a list after certain operations. Operations are performed until only one element is left.

Suppose I have a list which has certain elements 'marked' alternatively after a particular index $x$. For example, I begin with list: $[a, b, c, d, e, f', g, h', i]$ and $x=5$. The compliment symbol(or dash, whatever you call it) represents that this element is marked. Currently the last element not marked is $i$. Now every not marked element can mark the next not marked element. We always begin from the first index in the list. So, we begin from index $1$ and find that $a$ itself is not marked. Hence $a$ marks the next not marked element which is $b$. The next not marked element is $c$ which marks $d$ and so on. When we reach $e$, the next not marked element is $g$ so it is marked too. The last element, as we see, will not be marked by anyone. Also, since it's the last element it cannot mark anyone. After one iteration our list now becomes: $[a, b', c, d', e, f', g', h', i]$. The last element not marked after our first iteration is $i$.

For our second iteration we again begin with index $1$ and see that $a$ is not marked. $a$ hence marks next not marked element, which is $c$. $e$ marks $i$. Our list becomes: $[a, b', c', d', e, f', g', h', i']$. This time our last not marked element is $e$.

Finally $a$ will mark $e$ and $a$ will be our last remaining element. **So for every iteration we have to find the last not marked element in the list till only one element is left and no more iterations can be performed.**

Some things I concluded: The first element, here $a$, will always be the last element remaining. Also, the same element will be the last element not marked as in our previous iteration if the not marked elements is odd in our current iteration(Here it happened for our first iteration, $i$ was the last not marked element). I also found some similarities with Josephus problem but couldn't really connect it. I think there will be some recurrence relation connecting the indices and the number of not marked elements for a particular iteration.

I am hoping for some closed formula that can directly give me the index of the last not marked element or maybe some efficient technique rather than just brute force.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. This particular procedure cannot leave any element than the first one because it never can be marked. I do not think that the question is about this particular method (because the result is obvious) , but if not, which marking methods do you have in mind ?

Comment: @Peter I do not need to find the element after all my iterations are done. I need to find the last not marked element after every iteration.

Comment: OK, this makes sense.

Comment: @Peter Please feel free to clarify if you find anything doubtful or something that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First eliminate all elements marked before the first step.

Then, from the remaining elements, notice that after iteration k, the remaining numbers are on the positions $m\cdot2^k+1$, $m=0,1,\ldots$

So if you have $n$ unmarked elements in the beginning, the index of the last one in the reduced array will be for $m=\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2^k}\right\rfloor$

Of course, you have to map this index back into the original array in which you ignored the already marked elements.

Comment: Actually mapping the index was what I thought too. However, the original question had some different index numbering which made it harder. My index $1$ starts from $x$(variable that I mentioned) and after the list ends, the marking continues from the beginning to the index $1$. So for the example it is: $6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. This will be the index for each element starting from leftmost element. This made it a little harder to solve. Any help? @Momo

Comment: @sh1ve9 So your counting for marking starts at index  6, but you are still interested in the last unmarked element in the original array?

Comment: Yes for the given array marking starts at $6$ because here the index marked as $1$(Let's say my marking style) is $5$ in normal marking. I need the last not marked element in my marking style. So before all steps it was index $5$, then again $5$, then it was $1$ and finally $6$ @Momo

Comment: Then you simply solve from the middle to the end, and if no elements left there, you solve again from the whole (circular) array middle to middle. It might be a little messy, but it should work.

Comment: Hmm, couldn't really understand it. Maybe you could include this in the main answer? @Momo

Comment: Maybe we can do something like this. We know the last element before performing any iteration. Let's say it's index $t$, then whenever even elements are left unmarked for the $k$ iteration, the next unmarked element after iteration will be at $t - 2^k$ position. When numbers start getting negative, we can take mod with length of list. I tried for small lists, looks fine. What do you say? @Momo

Comment: Yes, this is what i was trying to say. Also, your counting might start from a marked number, which would make your formula even more messy, but still doable.